# Curl Post In Php

Tags: php, json, post, curl

I am firing `CURL` `POST` request with `json` data but still the content type of response is `text/plain`.
Where am I going wrong?

```
$data = array(
            "name" => "aaaaa",
            "email" => "aaa@aa.com",
            "password" =>"aaa",
            "gender" => "male",
                           );

$data1 = json_encode($data);

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://xxxx.xxx.xxx/register");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  $last = curl_getinfo($ch);
  print_r($result);
  print_r($last);
```

Response : -

```
Array
(
    [url] => http://xxxx.xxx.xxx/register
    [content_type] => text/plain
    [http_code] => 403
    [header_size] => 358
    [request_size] => 277
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 0.067338
    [namelookup_time] => 2.2E-5
    [connect_time] => 0.000448
    [pretransfer_time] => 0.007352
    [size_upload] => 161
    [size_download] => 9
    [speed_download] => 133
    [speed_upload] => 2390
    [download_content_length] => 9
    [upload_content_length] => 161
    [starttransfer_time] => 0.06731
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [redirect_url] => 

)
```

Comment: The page that is responding is not setting the correct mime type. You're sending something in JSON, they are answering in plain text. They do not have to respond in the same way ;) If you are posting to your own script, check that you're setting the correct mime type.

Answer (score 2):

That's the response. So that means the response from the server is in text/plain. Your request instead is application/json. If you want to set the mime-type of your own script you can use Header();